# jquery ,get everyhing beetwen 2 tags

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

So,I have this

```
 $(".carpeta").click(function(){
    var elementos = $(this).nextUntil('ul.segunda').html();
    $('.doc-doc').html(elementos);
});
```

With that

```
 <ul class="segunda"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close "></span><span class="dime carpeta""></span>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example1
    </li>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example2
    </li>
    <ul class="segunda"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close "></span><span class="dime carpeta""></span>
```

On click first ul I wanna get everything until next ul with the class ".segunda" but I only have the first li "example1".

Comment: Your markup is invalid. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is quite unclear.
Sorry, I have to say.

I can't figure out what these classes are for:

- .dime
- .carpeta
- .doc-doc

But I found out about [`.glyphicon`](http://glyphicons.com/).
**This finally gave me a real hint on what you what to do:**
*(Thanks, by the way, to make me discover it!)*

You want to toggle the display of `li`s onclick of an icon..oO( What else ? )
And you probably will want to close it when it's opened.

So here is a small script to do that:

```
$(".glyphicon-folder-open, .glyphicon-folder-close").click(function(){

    // Toggle display of folder icons and lis
    $(this).parent().children("span.glyphicon, li.tercera").each(function(){
        var correctDisplay = "block";
        if( $(this).hasClass("glyphicon") ){    // Icon need to be inline-block
            correctDisplay = "inline-block";
        }
        if( $(this).css("display") == "none" ){
            $(this).css("display",correctDisplay);
        }else{
            $(this).css("display","none");
        }
    });
});
```

Have a look at my working [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/oubtmppL/).

I added another glyphicon for folder opened.
I also added a `.description` class... Which maybe was the use of `.carpeta`...

Here is your HTML now:

```
<ul class="segunda">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
    <span class="description"> Numbers</span>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example 1
    </li>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example 2
    </li>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example 3
    </li>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example 4
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="segunda">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
    <span class="description"> Letters</span>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example A
    </li>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example B
    </li>
    <li class="tercera">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        Example C
    </li>
</ul>
<br>
```

And some CSS:

```
.tercera{
    display:none;
}
.glyphicon-folder-open{
    display:none;
}
.glyphicon{
    padding:6px 6px 0 0;
}
li{
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
```

**Final thought** about `.doc-doc`:

Because I have a feeling telling me it will be your next question...
If you want to display a documents content in a `div` somewhere... On `li` click:
Look for Ajax.